# Why cannot I install Lumia Video Trimmer on Lumia 435?

Tags: apps, video

I am using Lumia 435 Dual SIM with Lumia Denim Update 2. When I open a video that I have filmed using Lumia Camera, I am suggested to install Lumia Video Trimmer (fig. 1). But, when I go to Store, it is not available for my phone to install (fig. 2). Detailed info on the error are also shown in fig. 3. My phone is up to date and I connected using VPN to circumvent the possible problem of location availability, but still failed. What isn't it installed on my phone?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Connecting via a VPN does not change location availability - that is tied to your Microsoft Account. If you go to https://account.microsoft.com/, sign in with the primary account used on the phone, go to "Your Info" > "Edit your personal info", what country does it show?